# Semi-decidability of the language $\overline{L_{\epsilon}}$

Tags: turing-machines, proof-techniques, halting-problem, semi-decidability

Firstly consider the problem: given $L_H = \{R(M)w : M \in TM_0, w\in L(M)\}$ where $R(M)$ are encoded transitions of $M \in TM_0$. Assume for contradiction $\overline{L_{H}}$ is semi-decidable, then there is $Q \in TM_0$ with $L(Q)  = \overline{L_{H}}$ therefore for every $M \in TM_0$ we have the following
$$Q \ accepts \ input \ R(M)w \iff M \ does \ not \ accept \ input \ w  \ \ \ \ (1)$$
Then we construct machine $Z$ s.t. doubles the input and runs machine $Q$. Observe the following for arbitrary $M \in TM_0$:
\begin{alignat*}{2}
Z  \ accepts \ input \ R(M) &\iff Q\ accepts \ input \ R(M)R(M)\\
&\iff M \ does \ not  \ accept \ input \ R(M)
\end{alignat*}
Taking $M = Z$ will yield us a contradiction. Hence, $\overline{L_{H}}$ is not semi-decidable.

The same technique I am trying to apply for the case $L_{\epsilon} = \{R(M) : M \in TM_0 \ \text{s.t. $M$ accepts $\epsilon$}\}$ where $R(M)$ are encoded transitions of $M \in TM_0$. But I am facing some troubles. Assume for contradiction $\overline{L_{\epsilon}}$ is semi-decidable, then there is $Q \in TM_0$ with $L(Q)  = \overline{L_{\epsilon}}$ therefore for every $M \in TM_0$ we have the following
$$Q \ accepts \ input \ R(M) \iff M \ does \ not \ accept \ input \ \epsilon$$
Then I cannot really find appropriate $Z$ for this case, as doubling the input simply won't work. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: can you expand on the definition of $TM_0$ here?

Comment: is it just the set of all turing machines? why is there a "0" subscript there?

Comment: $TM_0$ is a set of all TM over binary alphabet

Comment: Then i think im misunderstanding something. Why would $Q$ terminate on $R(M)w$ if and only if $M$ doesnt terminate on $w$? I think you meant there to be: $Q$ **accepts** $R(M)w$ if and only if $M$ does not **accept** $w$.

The first part of the proof still would be correct (except for this small change)

Comment: So the second part just doubles the input and you get $R(M)R(M)$ which is accepted by $Q$, but then $M$ doesn't accept $R(M)$ by $(1)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume for contradiction $\overline{L_{\epsilon}}$ is semi-decidable. It's easily proven that $L_{\epsilon}$ is semi-decidable by reduction to the HALTING problem, i.e. $L_{H}$ is semi-decidable. If $L_{\epsilon}$ and $\overline{L_{\epsilon}}$ are semi-decidable, hence $L_{\epsilon}$ is decidable. This is a contradiction, as $L_{\epsilon}$ as well as $L_{H}$ are semi-decidable.

In this proof the following claim was used:

> $\textbf{Claim:} \text{ If $L$ and $\overline{L}$ are semi-decidable, then $L$ is decidable}$